# how to change color of header for all gridview in yii2?

Tags: gridview, colors, header, yii2

I want to change background color of header for all my `GridView` headers in Yii2. I know the following code does this work but I want to change only once, all of headers of the same color.

**code**:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            'attribute' => 'user_id',
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'background-color:#ccf8fe'],
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

What is should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding style options to each column seems to be the only way, but I can't guarantee. However, you're not limited to only that. The workaround solution:

1) Add this code somewhere in `GridView::widget` (for example, above `columns => [...]`:

```
 // ...
 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
 'options' => [
    'class' => 'YourCustomTableClass',
 ],
 // ...
```

2) Add new style rules to it (in `css` file):

```
.YourCustomTableClass table thead {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

CSS will apply background color (red) for header in each column. I have tested this myself to confirm it works.

Comment: @Digipng I'm glad that worked for you, too. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Since there is already a [default class on the gridview container](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/grid/GridView.php#L79), 
you don't need to change your gridview config, you should simply use this css rule :

```
.grid-view table thead {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: While it's true, it would apply to all GridViews, not just one. What if someone wants to apply just to one GridView? :)

Comment: Well, the question is about "I want change only once in code, all header of the same color"

Comment: Yeah, true, just asked (in case someone else wanted that way).