# how to apply css to particular column of gridview columns in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am new to yii2.. how to apply css to column, column heading of yii2 gridview??

```
<?php 

    $gridColumns = [
                     ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                     ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],  

                    'name',
                    'company_mail', //change the color of heading
                    'no_employees',
                    'email:email', 
                    .
                    .
                    .];
            echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ]); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set particular column style/css using this way.

```
$columns = [
   'onenormalcolumn',
   'anothercolumn',
   [
       'format'=>"ntext", // or other formatter
       'attribute' => 'theattributeofmodel',
       'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:50px'], // For TD
       'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'ur-class'] // For TH

   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your column in detailed mode:

```
<?php 
$columns = [
   'onenormalcolumn',
   'anothercolumn',
   [
       'format'=>"ntext", // or other formatter
       'attribute' => 'theattributeofmodel',
       'options'=>[ 'style'=>'your rules here' ]
   ]
]
?>
```

See [Yii2 Gridview column options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$options-detail)

Comment: I dont want to use directly .. want to give id or class... then apply style from css.. can you help??..... also i tried like this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241292/how-to-change-color-of-header-for-all-gridview-in-yii2.... but it is applying to content of table NOT to heading

Comment: Replace 'style' with 'class' in the example and set your class name as value.

Comment: 'options' => [
    'class' => 'YourCustomTableClass',
 ],

2) Add new style rules to it (in css file):

.YourCustomTableClass {
   color: #FF0000;
}...............It is NOT changing color of  column HEADING .. only changes color of table content/ ROWS

Answer (score 1):

if you want  change the column header css properties  you should use  headerOptions column propreties eg:

```
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

    .......
    'anothercolumn',
       [
        'format'=>"ntext", // or other formatter
        'attribute' => 'theattributeofmodel',
        'headerOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'background-color:#ccf8fe' ]
       ], 

],
```